# How can I see what keywords are searched most on Google during the last month?

Tags: keyword, google-trends

I'm currently analyzing keywords related to my business and I see how it can change the keyword selection process when you know what users are searching for.

Then I thought that it would be nice to know what is becoming popular among internet users of a specific country, this way I'll sense the market change easier. But I couldn't find options to see what keywords are most searched during a time period.

Does Google Trends provide users which such data?

How can I extract these data from Google Trends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the Trends page and enter an empty search query (just click the blue search button with no terms) you should be taken to the results page.

What this will show you is (I believe) the top searches (under "Related"). There is also a side-nav filter option to show you the results of the last 30 days among other options.

[image]

You can also check out the [Trends Help Center](http://support.google.com/trends/answer/99638?hl=en&ref_topic=19359) for more info. In particular, you can search for the top searches in a particular category:

> **How do I see the top searches within a category?**
>
> Without entering in
>   any search terms, choose a category using the drop-down menu. You can
>   also apply a location filter or a time filter using the appropriate
>   drop-down menus. Then, click Search.